# Is there a way to hide jboss methods from exception stacktrace print?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, stack-trace

When an exception occur, I need to scroll throw a lot of `at org.jboss....` lines. Is there a way to do not print those lines?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/03/filtering-irrelevant-stack-trace-lines.html

Comment: One thing to note about the linked blog post is WildFly and JBoss EAP do not use logback as the log manager.